# Android change fragment textview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am following this tutorial for create tab:http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1

I want to set textview(in games fragment) from main activity.I am trying with this code

This is games fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Game List"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/metin"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying with this code in oncreate activity(main activity)

```
TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.metin);
myAwesomeTextView.setText("My Awesome Text");
```

But app is crashing.How can I resolve it ?

Comment: What error are you getting when it crashes? Please provide a stack trace.

Comment: Also, where are you calling `findViewById()`?

Comment: Error log:http://prntscr.com/44mv7r

Answer (score 0):

It's probably crashing because of a null pointer exception, since you are calling `findViewById(R.id.metin)` which will search for the view inside the activity.

I recommend you set up a method inside the fragment that can pass itselft or its view as a parameter so you can call `view.findViewById(R.id.metin)` which is more likely to find your TextView.

Also remember to call the view once it has been attached to the main activity, otherwise you'll get another kind of null pointer exception. For this you need to be aware of the fragment's lifecycle.

Read this: [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)